# Windows 10 Doesn't Find Network Drives or Computers

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares

I just upgraded my computer from Windows 7 Ultimate to Win 10 Pro. After the process all my network drives have been disconnected and no longer appear under `Network` along with the other computers connected to the network. I have checked my Network sharing and discovery settings, and I can see the Win10 computer from other computers on the network, just not the other way around.

I followed the instruction given here: [Windows 10 computer can't connect to any other computer on the network](https://superuser.com/questions/954142/windows-10-computer-cant-connect-to-any-other-computer-on-the-network) however this did not solve my problem.

I am connected to the network via Ethernet, and was before as well.

Comment: Could be an issue with name resolution. Have you tried connecting to the shares using their IP address in the place of their name? For instance \\Networkshare1\Myfolder >> \\192.168.1.76\Myfolder

Answer (score 0):

#### If the network drives appear disconnected

Try opening them anyway; the disconnectedness is checked at login time, a time at which network connections may or may not be fully established. If you get a prompt for credentials, enter them; it's possible saved passwords got lost in the upgrade.

#### If the network drives disappeared

Recreate them. It's possible that they got lost in the upgrade; they should stay put after being made in Windows 10.

#### If you can't see other computers on the network

You probably need to enable network discovery and file sharing.

Open the desktop Control Panel (it's on the Win+X menu). If you're in Category view, choose *View network status and tasks*. If you're in one of the icon views, choose *Network and Sharing Center*. Then, on the left, click *Change advanced sharing settings*.

Expand *Private* or *Guest or Public* depending on what you've called your current network connection. (Private, hopefully.) Make sure *Turn on network discovery* and *Turn on file and printer sharing* are enabled, then press *Save changes*.

Comment: I already did that, the problem persists.

Comment: @Clefspeare13 Oh, I might have misread the question. Did just your mapped network drives disappear? What happens if you re-add them?

Comment: it tells me they are unavailable

Comment: @Clefspeare13 What happens if you click on them anyway? Does it prompt for credentials?

Comment: Win 8 and up enables encrypted credentials to shares with a local workgroup. Which mode of sharing are you using? Did you disable any services?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 does not support SMBv1 since build 1709. This blocks connection to legacy devices using this protocol.

Check:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-by-default-in-windows

On this page, MS describes some workarounds. If it does not work, you can enable SMBv1 following this approach:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and

I have an old NAS server. I had to enable SMBv1 to access my old files...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with Network Drives not appearing in the Network listing of File Explorer.   I fixed the problem with the steps described in the following article:
https://www.technipages.com/what-to-do-if-windows-cannot-map-network-drive.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1140027)